# Special characters in text

Tags: java, json

How to remove special characters in a value for ex. "Radial™". Due to presence of "TM" in "Radial" facing issues. Is there a way to remove such characters from entire json file. The special text could be dynamic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**non-US-ASCII (i.e. outside 0x0-0x7F)** characters

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "Radial™";
        s = s.replaceAll("[^\\x00-\\x7f]", "");
        System.out.println(s);
    }
```

**Output**

```
Radial
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only plan to only support US-ASCII you can just loop through the characters of the String and remove all that have a value higher than 255